# Logging on file android

Tags: android, logging, log4j, logback

I would like to use something like log4j to log on files. I can see the `logback` project but I can't understand how to use a FileAppender programmatically. 
Is There a simple way to log on files?

Comment: Means you looking for a class which you could use to write logs on file and save to sdcard? m i right?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for something like this. But I don't want to write on the sdcard I want to write on the application storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically create a `FileAppender` in [`logback-android`](http://tony19.github.io/logback-android), use the following code:

```
//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
//import org.slf4j.Logger;

//import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
//import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter;

//import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
//import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;
//import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
//import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

private void configureFileAppender() {
    // reset the default context (which may already have been initialized)
    // since we want to reconfigure it
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    context.reset();

    final String LOG_DIR = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/logs";

    FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    fileAppender.setAppend(true);
    fileAppender.setContext(context);
    fileAppender.setFile(LOG_DIR + "/log.txt");

    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setPattern("%logger{35} - %msg%n");
    encoder.setContext(context);
    encoder.start();

    fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
    fileAppender.start();

    // add the newly created appender to the root logger;
    // qualify Logger to disambiguate from org.slf4j.Logger
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger root = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    root.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
    root.addAppender(fileAppender);

    // DEBUG: print any status messages (warnings, etc) encountered in logback config
    //StatusPrinter.print(context);
}
```

You might want to consider using a `RollingFileAppender` instead to avoid filling up your disk. See example from the [`logback-android` Wiki](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki/Appender-Notes#configuration-in-code).

Answer (score 1):

To write Logs on SD Card i am using below class.
You can try or modify as per your need ,

```
    public class Log {

/** you can use application storage just change below line to your like getFile or package name etc.. **/   
        private static String enable_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/your foder name";
        private static File logFolderPath = new File(enable_path);

        private static boolean isLogEnabled(){
            return logFolderPath.exists();
        }

        public static void e(String tag, String msg) {
            if(isLogEnabled()){
                android.util.Log.e(tag, msg);
                put('E', tag, msg, null);
            }        
        }
        public static void e(String tag, String msg, Throwable thr) {
            if(isLogEnabled()){
                android.util.Log.e(tag, msg, thr);
                put('E', tag, msg + ": " + thr.getMessage(), thr);
            }        
        }

        private static final File LOG_FILE = new File(logFolderPath, "Logs.txt");
        private static FileWriter fw;
        private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ", Locale.US);
        private static long lastMs, lastNs;
        private synchronized static void put(char level, String tag, String msg,Throwable thr) {


            try {

                if(!LOG_FILE.exists())
                    LOG_FILE.createNewFile();

               /* if (fw == null)*/ {
                    fw = new FileWriter(LOG_FILE, true); // true: append
                }
                Date d = new Date();
                long nowMs = d.getTime();
                long nowNs = System.nanoTime();
                if (lastMs == 0)
                    lastMs = nowMs;
                if (lastNs == 0)
                    lastNs = nowNs;
                fw.write(level);
                fw.write(sdf.format(d));
                fw.write(Long.toString(nowMs - lastMs));
                fw.write(' ');
                fw.write(Long.toString(nowNs));
                fw.write(' ');
                fw.write(Double.toString((nowNs - lastNs) / 1e6));
                fw.write(' ');
                fw.write(tag);
                fw.write(' ');
                fw.write(msg);
                fw.write('\n');
                if (thr != null)
                    thr.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(fw));
                fw.flush();
                lastMs = nowMs;
                lastNs = nowNs;     
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                android.util.Log.e(tag, "IOException", ex); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's ok, but I would use an external logging library.